# Problems with margins and scroll bars

Tags: css, html

I'm mostly a C++ programmer who's getting involved in HTML5 and Javascript. I'm having some trouble with my layouts and am asking for advice and some criticism of how I'm doing it.

A reoccurring problem I'm having is unwanted scroll bars appearing when I add margin or padding. This is a mockup of a layout I'm working on for a Javascript application.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qy4Xz/

Each box uses class 'text-line' to produce a line that my controls go in. I wanted to add a margin so the costs box items would have some space around them. When I add a 5px margin to text-line, my geometry box has scroll bars in each left/right panel.

http://jsfiddle.net/LD5TS/

Here is where I'm adding the margins:

```
.text-line {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;  /* no margins */
}
```

This is probably a newbie mistake, but what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this? I run into this problem a lot, I've read a lot of material, but I'm missing something. If I'm making any other major layout mistakes can you point them out? Thank you!

Comment: Just a tip, when you have something like `margin: 0px;`, you don't need to write out the `px`.

Comment: Try using `padding` instead of `margin` so the content doesn't expand beyond it's container.

Comment: This is due to the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#various). When you specify a `width` or `height` it's related to the outer container which means a box will fit the container if you specify `100%`. A `margin` is _then_ added to that box, making it `W + P` in size. The padding is subtracted from the width making the effective box dimension `W - P`. Paddings cause scrollbar issues only if the children elements are bigger than that effective dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the *.text-line* elements have `width:100%;` they will naturally overflow the container if they have margin too, since margin does by default not get included in the `width` value.

What you could do if you want both space around the content *and* have the element fill its parent in width, is removing the `margin:5px` and adding this code to *.text-line*:

```
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
padding:5px;
```

What the code above does is including the padding *in* the width value, thus you can add padding and the element will still only get the `width` value you declared.

Answer (score 1):

try to add padding instead of margin and it will work fine. To understand exactly what's happening, please take a look at [css box model](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/)